# Dynamics CRM Connect - Map OptionSet and DateTime CRM fields to Sitecore

Tags: pipelines, data-exchange-framework

I am  mapping `Status Reason` from CRM which is an `Option Set` to a `Single Line of Text` field on Sitecore. I have checked the `Use Value Property`

[image]

but it returned the integer value of the option set.

[image]

I have seen http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DynamicsCrmConnect/v1.2/cookbooks/synchronization/option-set-values/index.html for mapping option set values but it works the other way around, i.e., Sitecore to CRM. I tried creating a Read Version of the code as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.DataAccess;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace DynamicsCrm
{
    public class EntityAttributeOptionSetValueReader : IValueReader
    {
        public EntityAttributeOptionSetValueReader(string attributeName)
        {
            this.AttributeName = attributeName;
        }

        public string AttributeName { get; private set; }

        public CanReadResult CanRead(object source, DataAccessContext context)
        {
            var canRead = false;
            var isGuess = false;
            if (source != null)
            {
                if (source is Entity)
                {
                    canRead = true;
                    isGuess = true;
                }
            }
            return new CanReadResult { CanReadValue = canRead, IsGuess = isGuess };
        }

        public ReadResult Read(object source, DataAccessContext context)
        {            
            var entity = source as Entity;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                if (entity.Attributes.ContainsKey(this.AttributeName))
                {
                    if (entity.Attributes[this.AttributeName] is OptionSetValue)
                    {
                        //var value2 = entity.Attributes[this.AttributeName] as OptionSetValue;
                        int value = (entity.Attributes[this.AttributeName] as OptionSetValue).Value;
                        //value2.Value = (int)value;
                        //return new ReadResult { ReadValue = 2 };

                        // Get the raw option set value and return the label
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    entity.Attributes[this.AttributeName] = new OptionSetValue((int)value);
                    //return true;
                }
            }
            //return false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm stuck with the `Read` method because I don't know what specifically is `ReadValue` since it's an object. I'm unfamiliar with this and cannot find examples in the documentation and I would really appreciate your guidance. As for `DateTime`, it doesn't map the correct value too and return the following:

[image]

There are no problems with strings and single line of texts. Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Vlad, here is my code I've patterned from http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DynamicsCrmConnect/v1.2/cookbooks/synchronization/option-set-values/add-value-writer.html

EntityAttributeValueAccessorConverterEx.cs

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Repositories;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.DataAccess;
using Sitecore.Services.Core.Model;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.DynamicsCrm.Converters.DataAccess.ValueAccessors;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.DynamicsCrm.Models.ItemModels.DataAccess;
using DynamicsCrm;

namespace DynamicsCrm
{
    public class EntityAttributeValueAccessorConverterEx : EntityAttributeValueAccessorConverter
    {
        public EntityAttributeValueAccessorConverterEx(IItemModelRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
        }
        public override IValueAccessor Convert(ItemModel source)
        {
            var accessor = base.Convert(source);
            if (accessor != null && accessor.ValueReader == null)
            {
                var useValueProperty = base.GetBoolValue(source, EntityAttributeValueAccessorItemModel.UseValueProperty);
                if (useValueProperty)
                {
                    string attributeName = base.GetStringValue(source, EntityAttributeValueAccessorItemModel.AttributeName);
                    accessor.ValueReader = new EntityAttributeOptionSetValueReader(attributeName);
                }
            }
            return accessor;
        }
    }
}
```

EntityAttributeOptionSetValueReader.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.DataAccess;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace DynamicsCrm
{
    public class EntityAttributeOptionSetValueReader : IValueReader
    {
        public EntityAttributeOptionSetValueReader(string attributeName)
        {
            this.AttributeName = attributeName;
        }

        public string AttributeName { get; private set; }

        public CanReadResult CanRead(object source, DataAccessContext context)
        {
            var canRead = false;
            var isGuess = false;
            if (source != null)
            {
                if (source is Entity)
                {
                    canRead = true;
                    isGuess = true;
                }
            }
            return new CanReadResult { CanReadValue = canRead, IsGuess = isGuess };
        }

        public ReadResult Read(object source, DataAccessContext context)
        {            
            var entity = source as Entity;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                if (entity.Attributes.ContainsKey(this.AttributeName))
                {
                    if (entity.Attributes[this.AttributeName] is OptionSetValue)
                    {
                        //var value2 = entity.Attributes[this.AttributeName] as OptionSetValue;
                        string statusCodeStr = entity.FormattedValues[this.AttributeName];
                        //value2.Value = (int)value;
                        return new ReadResult(DateTime.Now) { ReadValue = statusCodeStr, WasValueRead = true };

                        // Get the raw option set value and return the label
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ReadResult(DateTime.Now) { ReadValue = String.Empty, WasValueRead = false };
                    //return true;
                }
            }
            //return false;
            return new ReadResult(DateTime.Now) { ReadValue = String.Empty, WasValueRead = false };
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Converter Type` in the template's standard value, I wrote `DynamicsCrm.EntityAttributeValueAccessorConverterEx, DynamicsCrm`. I tried debugging it (the DLL is in `inetpub/wwwroot/sitecoreinstance/website/bin`) but didn't hit the breakpoint. Does the code make sense or am I missing something? Thank you very much!

Comment: Code under 'if (accessor != null && accessor.ValueReader == null)' will not be performed. 'accessor.ValueReader' is not null.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get string value instead of int value you need to update your reader with:

```
string statusCodeStr = entity.FormattedValues[this.AttributeName];
```

Here is debug result:

[image]

According to `DateTime` mapping.
Adam Conn has already answered. The solution is to use `ISO Date Value Reader` for the transformer. 
[POCO DateTime not mapping correctly in Data Exchange Framework](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/poco-datetime-not-mapping-correctly-in-data-exchange-framework)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `DateTime` mapping is now working. As for the `OptionSet` I've deployed the code (please see edit) but nothing happened. I also can't debug it. Is the trigger to run the pipeline? Even though I attached it to `w3wp` it didn't hit the breakpoint. Please see edited question above.

Comment: 1. If you use your own template for the "EntityAttributeValueAccessorConverterEx" you need to add supported id.
2. You overrides  "Convert" method of EntityAttributeValueAccessorConverter and use "base.Convert". accessor.ValueReader is not null in base class. It means all code under the "if" block will not be performed. 3. Use Value Property shouldn't be set